# Text Adventure Game: Take and Inventory

Tags: java, adventure

There are a couple of tasks I need to complete and I need a little guidance.

First, I have to have the T command which allows the player to take the item that is in the current room they are in. The items for each room are in their respective Locale arrays. By using itemPresent it takes the item that the player1 current room is originally set to and the room is not updated throughout the game, instead it is updated within the move() method. I wanted to use roomData[2] to get the item that way, but since I can't take a variable from another method, I am unable to do this. So, how would I be able to take the item from the current room?

Second, I need to remove the item from the room once it is taken so that an item can't be taken twice.

Third, I would have to add this taken item to the player's inventory which I tried to set up using an ArrayList. I am not sure how to set up the code so that I can take the item I just found and add it to the inventory.

Thank you for all help!!

Here is my main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class GameEngine {

  static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


  static String[] playerInfo = {"playerName"};

  static Player player1 = new Player("playerName", null, 0, 0);


 //Welcome Message
 public static void displayIntro(){
    System.out.println("\tWelcome to Power Outage!");
    System.out.println("=================================================");
    System.out.print("\tLet's start by creating your character.\n\tWhat is your name? ");

    //Will read what name is entered and return it
     playerInfo[0]= userInput.nextLine();

    System.out.println("\tHello, " +playerInfo[0]+ ". Let's start the game! \n\tPress any key to begin.");
    System.out.print("=================================================");

    //Will move to next line when key is pressed
    userInput.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\tYou wake up in your bedroom. \n\tThe power has gone out and it is completely dark. \n"
            +"\tYou must find your way to the basement to start the generator. \n\tMove in any direction by typing, "
            + "'N', 'S', 'E', or 'W'.\n\tType 'H' at any time for help and 'Q' "
            + "to quit the game. Good luck!\n\tPress any key.");

    userInput.nextLine();
 }

 //Locations {roomName, description, item}
 static String[][] Locale ={
         {"bedroom","You see the outline of a bed with your childhood stuffed bear on it.","map"},
         {"hallway","A carpeted floor and long pictured walls lie ahead of you.",null},
         {"kitchen","The shining surface of your stove reflects the pale moonlight coming in the window over the sink.","battery"},
         {"bathroom","You find yourself standing in front of a mirror, looking back at yourself.","flashlight"},
         {"living room","You stub your toe on the sofa in the room, almost falling right into the TV.","battery"},
         {"dining room","You bump the china cabinet which holds your expensive dishes and silverware.","key"},
         {"office","The blinking light from the monitor on your desk can be seen in the dark",null},
         {"library","The smell of old books surrounds you.","battery"},
         {"basement","You reach the top of some stairs and upon descending down, you find the large metal generator.",null},     
 };

 //Matrix for rooms
 static int[][] roomMap = {
            //   N,E,S,W
                {6,1,-1,-1}, //Bedroom (room 0)
                {4,2,3,0}, //Hallway (room 1)
                {-1,-1,5,1}, //Kitchen (room 2)
                {1,-1,-1,-1}, //Bathroom (room 3)
                {-1,7,1,-1}, //Living Room (room 4)
                {2,-1,-1,-1}, //Dining Room (room 5)
                {-1,-1,0,-1}, //Office (room 6)
                {8,-1,-1,4}, //Library (room 7)
                {-1,-1,7,-1} //Basement (room 8)
                };

  //Items
  private String paperMap = "map";
  private String key = "key";
  private String flashlight = "flashlight";
  private String battery = "battery";


  static int currentLocation = player1.currentRoom;

  //take method
    //String[] currentInventory = {};
    // player1.inventory = currentInventory;
  /*
    private static int[] itemNames = {"map","key","flashlight","battery"};
    for(int i=0; i<itemNames.length; i++){
        if(itemNames[i].equals("map")){

        }
    }
    */

  //inventory
  ArrayList<String> inventory = new ArrayList<String>();

  //static String[] itemPresent = roomData[2];


  //move method
  private static String[] dirNames = {"North", "East", "South", "West"};

  private static void move(int dir) {
      int dest = roomMap[currentLocation][dir];
      if (dest >= 0 && dest != 8) {
          System.out.println("=================================================");
          System.out.println("\tYou have moved " + dirNames[dir]);
          currentLocation = dest;
          String[] roomData = Locale[currentLocation];
          System.out.println("\tYou are in the "+roomData[0]+".");
          System.out.println("\t"+roomData[1]);
          String itemPresent = roomData[2];
      } 
      else if (dest == 8){
          System.out.println("\tCongratulations!! You have found the basement and turned on the generator! \n\tYou have won the game!");
            System.out.println("\tTHANKS FOR PLAYING!!!!!!");
            System.out.println("\tCopyright 2016 \n\n");
            stillPlaying = false;
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("\tThere is no exit that way, please try again.");
      }
  }

  //All possible responses to keys pressed
  public static void pressedKey(){
      while(stillPlaying){
      String response = userInput.nextLine();
      if(player1.currentRoom != 8 && !response.equalsIgnoreCase("Q") ){
          if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("M")){
              //only print if the player has the map
              System.out.println("Here is your map: \n\n\t\t\tbasement\n\noffice\t  living room\tlibrary\n\nbedroom\t   hallway\tkitchen\n\n\t   bathroom \tdining room");
              break;
          }
          else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("T")){
              // check if there is an item in the player's current room
              if( itemPresent != null){
                  // if there is, then add it to the player's inventory and remove it from the locale
                  System.out.println("You have gained: " +itemPresent+ ". This adds the item to your inventory and you get 5 points added to your score!");
                  //add to inventory--- player1.inventory itemPresent;
                  player1.score = +5;
                  //remove item from the locale  
              }
              else{
                  System.out.println("There is no item to take in this room.");
              }
          }
          else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
              System.out.println("To move, type 'N' for North, 'S' for South, 'W' for West, or 'E' for East."
                    +"\nTry to navigate to the basement to turn on the generator."
                    +"\nTake an item from the room you are in by pressing 'T'."
                    +"\nCheck your inventory by pressing 'I'."
                    + "\nYou can type 'Q' at any time to quit the game.\n");
              break;
          }
          else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("I")){
              System.out.println("These are the items in your inventory: "+player1.inventory+".");
          }
          else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
              move(0);
              break;
          }
          else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
              move(1);
              break;
          }
          else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
              move(2);
              break;
          }
          else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("W")){
              move(3);
              break;
          }
          else{
              System.out.println("\tInvalid command!");
          }

      }//End of if statement
      else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
          System.out.println("Thanks for playing!\n\n");
          stillPlaying = false;
      }

    }//End of while 
  }//End of pressedKey method


static boolean stillPlaying = true; //When this is true, the game continues to run


public static void main(String[] args) {    
    displayIntro();
    System.out.println("=================================================");
    System.out.println("\tYou are in the bedroom.");

    while(stillPlaying){//This makes the game continue to loop

        System.out.println("=================================================");
        System.out.println("\tMove in any direction.");

        pressedKey();


    } //End of while
} //End of main
} //End of class
```

This is my Player class

```
public class Player {
    //import java.util.Scanner;


    //Player class must have name, location, inventory, and score
    //Instead of array of descriptions, use array of Locale objects

        private String playerName;
        public String inventory;
        public int score;
        public int currentRoom;

        public Player(String playerName, String inventory, int score, int currentRoom){
            this.playerName = playerName;
            this.inventory = inventory;
            this.score = 0;
            this.currentRoom = currentRoom;
        }
    }
```

This is my Locale class

```
public class Locale {
//Locale must have name, description, and item


private String roomName;
private String description;
private String item;

public Locale(String roomName, String description, String item){
    this.roomName = roomName;
    this.description = description;
    this.item = item;
}
}
```

Comment: “if I try to add an item … there is an error.”  That error is very valuable information;  it tells you (and us) what went wrong and where.  Edit your question and include the entire stack trace of that error.

Comment: Just a side note:  You're writing insanely procedural code in Java, which is designed to be an Object Oriented language.  What are your goals for this project?

Comment: The player needs to move through the map of rooms and be able to pick up objects and add them to their inventory. I currently have all the move functions working so the whole map is accessible, but the T and I commands I haven't fully finished yet. I have some comments in the T command section if that helps